# LLDB warning : Unable to resolve the breakpoint location

Tags: lldb

I am trying to debug a program with lldb and clang.

Error is thrown

> Breakpoint 1: no locations (pending).
>   WARNING:  Unable to resolve breakpoint to any actual locations

I am trying it on Windows 10 and have latest version of clang (8.0)

I am trying with a command to compile a program with this `clang -g -O0 test.c -o test` and to debug I am giving `lldb test` and for breakpoint 
`b test.c:3`

I am actually looking for debug information . But nothing seems to be working fine...any solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same thing on ubuntu , with same command and everything works correctly.
I think Windows version of LLDB still under development.